# Elliptic curve over field $\mathbb{C}(\lambda)$

Tags: elliptic-curves, modular-forms

I have the following problems on my modular forms course final exam:

Over field $\mathbb{C}(\lambda)$ equation
$y^2 =x(x−1)(x−\lambda)$
defines an elliptic curve $E_{\lambda}$ with a base in 2-torsion. 
Express $\lambda$ as a function of $z$  (curve $E_{\lambda}$ equals $\mathbb{C}/(\mathbb{Z+Z}z)$ ).

Unfortunately, I have no idea how one can solve it. 
So, any hints, links, solutions are more than welcome.

Comment: Express in which terms? It depends on which modular forms you can consider given. There's a few representations here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_lambda_function